# Getting Same data on all notifications

Tags: android, apple-push-notifications, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am creating an events and I want to create notification for events. For this I have used an alarm manager and broadcast receiver.

I have passed the event data with intent which is used to call broadcast receiver, but I am getting the same data for every notification.

What's going wrong here?

setting alarm

```
public void setNotificationTime(Calendar c)
{

    Date dateFrom = new Date();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        dateFrom = df.parse(startTime);
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {

    }

    dateFrom.getTime();
    c.setTime(dateFrom);

    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if(notificationTime !=null  &&  !notificationTime.isEmpty()) {


        if (notificationTime.equals("10 Minutes Before")) {

            FLAG = 1;

            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 10);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
            // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

            SetDay(c);

            notification = c.getTime();
            notificationTime = df.format(notification);

           // setAlarm(c, FLAG);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);

            intent.putExtra("startTime",startTime);
            intent.putExtra("endTime",endTime);
            intent.putExtra("location",location);
            intent.putExtra("title",eventTitle);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0 , intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notificationTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
}
```

Notification Receiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


public static int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Notification myNotification;
private String location,title,fromDate,toDate;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int id = rand.nextInt(1000000) + 1;

    Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        Date date1 = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

    fromDate =  intent.getStringExtra("startTime");
    toDate = intent.getStringExtra("endTime");
    location = intent.getStringExtra("location");
    title = intent.getStringExtra("title");


    try {
        date = df.parse(fromDate);
        date1 = df.parse(toDate);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {

    }


    String timeFrom = df2.format(date);
    //   String startTime = String.valueOf(timeFrom);

    String timeTo = df2.format(date1);
    // String endTime = String.valueOf(timeTo);



    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if(location.equals(""))
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo;

            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        else
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo + "\nAt : " + location;
            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        Log.i("Notify", "Notification");
        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(id, myNotification);

        myNotification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        MY_NOTIFICATION_ID++;


    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are reusing the same `PendingIntent` since you are creating it using a similar `Intent`. Given that the only difference between you intents is the extra data,
Android classifies them as same `intents` therefore instead of creating a new `PendingIntent`, the existing one is reused. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

try using `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` when creating your `PendingIntent` or ensure `Intent` attributes considered by `Intent.filterEquals` are different for every new `PendingIntent`